# Circular reference instantiation

Tags: javascript, oop, circular-reference

I want to instantiate two classes which both depend on each other like so:

```
this.a = null;
this.b = null; 
this.a = new A({
  b: this.b
}
this.b = new B({
  a: this.a
}
```

The problem is if I do so `b` is null if I hand it to the constructor. How can I solve this chicken or the egg problem in an "elegant" way? Or do I have to set the reference to `b` after the instantiation via a method?

Comment: Do it in the constructors of `A` and `B`. E.g. for `A`, if it was passed `null`, set `this.b = new B(this);`. When `B` is passed an `a != null`, the recursion ends. Same way for `A` and `B` swapped.

Comment: I think the only way is to use a setter to complete the loop after both objects are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving the problem to the constructors of `A` and `B`.

You can leverage conditional (indirect) recursion in this case:

```
function A(b)
{
    this.b = b || new B(this);
}
function B(a)
{
    this.a = a || new A(this);
}
```

By using `||`, you ensure that a call to `A(this)` and `B(this)` will not themselves create another `B`/`A` respectively, thus ending the "chicken/egg" problem.

Then you can use them like

```
this.a = new A();
this.b = this.a.b;
```

or

```
this.b = new B();
this.a = this.b.a;
```

If there are cases where `A` or `B` legitimately have their `.b` or `.a` set to `null`, you could use `undefined` and `null` to distinguish those cases, and change the constructors accordingly:

```
function A(b)
{
    this.b = b === undefined ? new B(this) : b;
}
function B(a)
{
    this.a = a === undefined ? new A(this) : a;
}
```

If `A` and `B` require other arguments to their constructor, or should for some other reason not construct another `B` or `A` themselves, you could pass them the `this` instance from the creating scope (since that holds `a` and `b` fields, whose value will be determined only when accessed, not when `A` and `B` are constructed):

```
function A(container)
{
    this.container = container;
    // Access B via this.container.b
}
function B(container)
{
    this.container = container;
    // Access A via this.container.a
}
this.a = new A(this);
this.b = new B(this);
```

If `A` and `B` are not meant to have full access to the container object, you could create intermediary objects to be used in its place, like:

```
var aProxy = { a: null };
var bProxy = { b: null };
this.a = aProxy.a = new A(bProxy);
this.b = bProxy.b = new B(aProxy);
```

If that is also unacceptable for some reason, then your only option is to later change the value of `a.b` and `b.a` by means of manual assignment or via a setter function.

Comment: But notice that this approach couples the two classes themselves together tightly, instead of letting their container do the work and pass the instances.

Comment: This is the reason it will not work for me. I think I have to make the assignment by setter even though it's a bit dirty.

Comment: @landunder To be clear, the first two approaches tie the classes together, the latter two (where A and B are passed a container) don't.